# Proving existence of point in an interval where integral's value is 0

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

I am trying to prove the following statement:

"Let $a<c<b$ and $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be Riemann integrable. If $\int_{a}^{c} f >0$ and $\int_{a}^{b} f < 0$, then there exists $t \in (c, b)$ such that $\int_{a}^{t}f = 0$."

I have attempted breaking apart the integral to obtain the conclusion, but have had no luck in doing so. So far my attempt is as follows:

Since $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, $f$ is integrable on $[a,c]$ and $[c,b]$, and
\begin{equation}\left[\int_{a}^{b}f = \int_{a}^{c}f + \int_{c}^{b}f\right] < 0\end{equation}
by our original assumption that $\int_{a}^{b} f < 0$. Then, because $\int_{a}^{c} f >0$, it follows that $\int_{c}^{b}f< 0$, otherwise we would contradict our assumption that $\int_{a}^{b} f < 0$. Thus, for some $t\in[c,b]$,
\begin{equation}\left[\int_{c}^{b}f = \int_{c}^{t}f + \int_{t}^{b} f\right] < 0.\end{equation}
Thus, substituting (2) back into (1) we observe
\begin{equation}\left[\int_{a}^{b}f = \int_{a}^{c}f + \int_{c}^{t}f + \int_{t}^{b} f\right] < 0.\end{equation}

It seems to me that if it was possible to show the integrals $\int_{a}^{c}f$ and $\int_{c}^{t}f$ cancel, then the result would follow. But so far I am stuck at this point and unable to think of anything that would help solve the problem. It seems that I am going about this problem incorrectly, but I am having trouble with thinking of another angle of approaching the problem from. Any suggestions/tips are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you recall the intermediate value theorem?  Do you recall that the fundamental theorem of calculus tells you that $\int_a^t f$ is differentiable, hence continuous?

Comment: @EricTowers It isn't necessarily differentiable unless $f$ is continuous. But it is Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: @EricTowers I can see how $F(t) = \int_{a}^{t}f$ would be continuous, but it is still a little unclear to me how we use the assumptions that $\int_{a}^{c}f > 0$ and $\int_{a}^{b}f <0$ along with the IVT. I will have to give some more thought to it, but I appreciate your response it was very helpful. +1